# Iframe cross-origin issue when using srcdoc

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I need to display an input from user that is html, I don't want user to be able to use script here so i'm using the sandbox mode of iframe to have content without script.

```html
<iframe class="frame"
        srcdoc="<h1>title</h1><p>content1</p><p>content2</p>"
        sandbox=""
        style="width:100%;border:none;overflow:hidden;">
 </iframe>
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to resize this frame to match the height of it's content with the bellow function but I can't access to `iFrame.contentWindow.document` due to cross-origin.

```js
function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {
    iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue. The problem was coming from the sandbox mode that is restricting everything so I needed to allow the javascript from same origin to be able to access it from my page :

```html
<iframe class="frame"
        srcdoc="<h1>title</h1><p>content1</p><p>content2</p>"
        sandbox="allow-same-origin"
        style="width:100%;border:none;overflow:hidden;">
 </iframe>
```